# Shorthand comparison ends up being too long to understand

Tags: ios, objective-c

There's a "Clamp" function from a library of Ray Wenderlich class's - SKTUtils to be exact. This clamp function is written in shorthand but in a way that I can't seem to understand. This clamps purpose is to limit a position to an area - the games "camera" follows the _player.position, while making sure the the player never sees the nothingness outside the game map. Here's the function:

```
CGFloat Clamp(CGFloat value, CGFloat min, CGFloat max)
{
    return value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value;
}
```

Here is the method it's used in, which the method it self gets used inside 'didFinishUpdate' method:

```
-(CGPoint)pointToCenterViewOn:(CGPoint)centerOn
{   
    CGFloat x = Clamp(centerOn.x, self.size.width/2,  _backgroundLayer.layerSize.width -  self.size.width/2); //Value, Min, Max.
    CGFloat y = Clamp(centerOn.y, self.size.height/2, _backgroundLayer.layerSize.height - self.size.height/2);

    return CGPointMake(-x, -y);
}


-(void)didFinishUpdate
{
    _worldNode.position = [self centerViewOnPoint:_player.position];
}
```

Can someone explain this?

```
value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value
```

I could only partially understand the shorthands beginning:

```
if (value < min)
{
    value = min;
}
else if (value > min)
{
    value > max??????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the explanation of `value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value`

```
if (value < min)
{
    return min
}
else
{
    if (value > max)
    {
        return max
    }
    else
    {
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright! Thank you. In 6 minutes I'll be able to accept this answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence is partially involved here. This would be made a lot nicer with some parentheses to aid reading. The comparison operators bind tighter than the ternary conditional, so you have:

```
(value < min) ? min : ((value > max) ? max : value)
```

From there it's just evaluated left-to-right. The only tricky bit is that the  else branch of the first conditional operator is itself another conditional operator. This would be the equivalent of an `else if` were you to expand it. The else branch of the second conditional is thus the else for the whole expression.

To convert this to `if` statements, then, you would do:

```
CGFloat retVal;
if( value < min ){
    retVal = min;
}
else if( value > max ){
    retVal = max;
}
else {
    retVal = value;
}

return retVal;
```

You might also prefer this way to clamp a value:

```
MAX(min_limit, MIN(value, max_limit))
```

which uses the `MAX` and `MIN` macros to evaluate to the lower of `max_limit` or `value` and the higher of that or `min_limit`, producing a result in the range between `min_limit` and `max_limit` (inclusive). The effect is the same; I think that's easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.